# Synonymize [swift-closures] to [closures]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

No one is going to ask a question about [swift-closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift-closures) without also needing to tag the question with the language tag [swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift).

Importantly, there's nothing special about [swift-closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift-closures) versus, say, Objective-C, that someone writing a multi-language app might want to use [swift-closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift-closures)[objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/objective-c).

As far as I can tell, [swift-closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift-closures) looks only to be an unnecessarily language-specific version of the [closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/closures) tag.

Therefore, [swift-closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift-closures) should be made a synonym of [closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/closures).

Comment: Sounds entirely plausible to me.  Now to get some people who have enough rights on the tags to suggest and approve the synonym.

Answer (score 10):

I went to look and there were just 28 questions with the tag [swift-closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift-closures), and 3 of those already had the tag [closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/closures).  Now all 28 questions have the tag [closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/closures) and none have the tag [swift-closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift-closures).  It wasn't a solo effort by me; [nhgrif](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2792531/nhgrif) helped with a [few retags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300129/synonymize-swift-closures-to-closures/300161?noredirect=1#comment225602_300161) too, before I identified the 28.  (If anyone else did any swift edits of the [swift-closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift-closures) tag, let me know so I can give credit where credit's due.)

I've updated the tag wiki short entry to say "Please do NOT use this tag; use the tag 'closures' instead."  So, the tag should vanish shortly unless someone adds some questions to the tag today or tomorrow.  There'll be one unhappy would-be taxonomist, but everyone else will be content.

*[…48 hours or so later…]* Because the [swift-closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift-closures) tag no longer exists, there is no longer a need to synonymize it with anything.

Comment: I removed about 3 [swift-closures] this morning when I was creating this question, but that's about it.

Comment: @nhgrif: OK; thanks for the information. When there are fewer than 100 questions tagged, it is usually simplest to get one or a few people who agree (after checking on MSO that there's no objection) to replace the tags. Tags with zero questions vanish automatically, so once the original set of questions is cleaned up, there won't often be new questions in the tag. It's worth quoting the statistics on the tag in the question. It helps people understand. (If there's a thousand questions, then it takes more organization or a request to 'The Team' (@SO) to do it sensibly. There's a big gray area.)

Comment: I give it six months until someone says we need to burninate closures by saying "you can't be an expert in closures because they're each different in different languages".

Comment: @corsiKa: mebbe, but since there should be a language tag along with the closures tag, that argument shouldn't hold much water.  We can review in due course.

Comment: The only interrogant is, is the synonymization still needed.

Comment: @Braiam: No—the [tag:swift-closures] doesn't exist any more, so there is nothing to synonymize.

Comment: There are 15 open ones now. We can clean it in less than 5 minutes, but can you check once and verify that the same argument still holds? Thanks!

Comment: Several of them already have [tag:closures] as well as [tag:swift-closures].  I'm no Swift expert, but I don't think the argument has changed.  I'll start at the bottom.

Comment: I started at the bottom and reached the top; there is closure once more on [tag:swift-closures] — @BhargavRao.

Comment: Cool, thanks so much! I'm checking the [completed] requests, and many have resurfaced. (around 15).

Comment: @BhargavRao — Ever played Whack-a-Mole?  :D

Comment: It's harder with tags ... and you know it :p