# Which swift tag should I use?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request, synonym-request, tag-synonym-process

## Welcome to Swift

Under [this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms) synonyms link, filter synonyms to 'swift'

You'll see this:
[swift3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift3.1), [swift3.0.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift3.0.2), [swift3.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift3.0.1), [swift3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift3.0) all map to [swift3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift3)

You'll also see this:
[swift2.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift2.3), [swift2.2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift2.2.1), [swift2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift2.2), [swift2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift2.1), [swift2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift2.0) all map to [swift2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift2)

Finally, you'll see this:
[swift-language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift-language), [swift-ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift-ios), [swift1.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift1.2) all map to [swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift)

---

It's very challenging to determine whether to use [swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift) or [swift3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift3) or both.
There are over 10,000 questions marked as `swift3` but not `swift`
There are over 4,000 questions marked as `swift2` but not `swift`
There are over 4,000 questions marked as `swiftui` but not `swift`
There are over 2,000 questions marked as `swift4` but not `swift`
There are almost 700 questions marked as `swift5` but not `swift`.

These 20,000 questions are all swift-related, but not tagged as swift.

---

Finally, some questions have `swift` *and* `swift2` *and* `swift3` etc. This is very vague. New questions are posed today as having to do with `swift3` when they aren't.

Because of how they are <sub><sup>mis</sup></sub>used, I propose that [swift2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift2), [swift3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift3), [swift4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift4), [swift5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift5) all qualify as synonyms to [swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift). We can add a new tag for version-specific questions. For example: [swift-version-changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift-version-changes)

---

## Tag Definitions

These tag definitions make a lot of sense, but most users never read these.

> [swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift): Swift is a safe, fast, and expressive general-purpose programming language developed by Apple Inc. for its platforms and Linux. Swift is open-source. Use the tag only for questions about language features, or requiring code in Swift. Use the tags [ios], [ipados], [macos], [watch-os], [tvos], [cocoa-touch], and [cocoa] for (language-agnostic) questions about the platforms or frameworks.

> [swiftui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swiftui): SwiftUI is Apple's declarative Swift API for defining graphical user interfaces. Use this tag for questions about SwiftUI on any platform.

> [swift2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift2), [swift3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift3), [swift4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift4), [swift5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift5): Use this tag only for questions directly related to changes in version N of Apple's Swift programming language. Use the tag [swift] for more general language questions, or the tags [ios], [cocoa], [apple-watch] etc. for questions about developing on Apple platforms. *- Notice how these tags were created specifically for locating changes in Swift? These are Definitely not used correctly*

---

## Research

[How can I dispute tag synonyms](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253382/how-can-i-dispute-a-tag-synonym)
 - "Can I ask them to be repealed?"
 - "Sure, and meta is totally the right place to do that. But you're going to have to make a good argument."
 - "Remember, splitting traffic between two tags is bad." `(In Swift's case, it's like 6 tags)`

[Are 2D-Array and 3D-Array both Multidimensional Arrays?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274888/version-specific-synonyms-2d-array-3d-array-multidimensional-array)
 - These are now synonyms.

[Swift-closures to closures](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300129/synonymize-swift-closures-to-closures)
 - "No one is going to ask a question about swift-closures without also needing to tag the question with the language tag swift."

[Should [swift2] be [swift] too?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302314/should-swift2-be-swift-too)
 - Read this! This closely related and highly upvoted question has gone unanswered and inactive. Now there are many new swift versions.
 - "I'd say it's time to burninate swift2 and merge it into swift."

Comment: Sounds very similar to the [html5 tag issue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385027/make-html5-a-synonym-of-html)

Comment: same with python-2 and python-3, and java version tags... Lots of tags with versions struggle with split traffic because people don't read tagging guidance.

Comment: @Zoe do they need to? For most questions, they are irrelevant to the version of the language. Yes, the implementation may be different, but if my question is "how to write a hello world?" there shouldn't be a question for every version of the language. (ie. that question in python should have 2-3 answers)